# Custom login -> admin

Tags: 8

I know it is *possible*, but is it *advisable* or even *in common sense* to try to implement second (own) login i.e. `mysite.com/login2` and access that way to custom layout (admin page), where is some custom data to manage our own hidden things, nothing related to drupal tho.

The reason for this, I love drupal, and I would use it for frontend publishing and managing site easy. But thing is I need some sort of portal (module for drupal) to handle data from my other sources where this own login and admin comes handy.

This is currently done with custom coding, but is it possible to integrate this "custom code" to drupal with modules and use durpals see, friendly urls, database handling etc advantages?

I don't expect this to happen in no time, need to learn a lot deeper but if there is a change to do this in reasonable time and without breaking drupal itself, I would love to start developing this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you would like for one login to give access to Drupal site administrative functionality, and also give access to specialist non-Drupal functionality.

The easiest and most flexible way to achieve this is might be to add an extra link to the Drupal administrative menu. When someone logs in, that new link would be there prominently along side the other Drupal administrative links.

The link could point to another website, to non-Drupal pages and scripts on the same server, or to Drupal pages generated by a custom Drupal module you created.

Perhaps the biggest advantage of putting your custom code inside a custom Drupal module would be that you could use Drupal's access control system: logging into Drupal with the right role would automatically grant users (and only these users) access to your custom functionality.

Generally speaking, taking existing code and turning it into a Drupal module so that it outputs it results "through" Drupal in a minimal but viable way should be easy.

Fully converting your code to take advantages of all Drupal's API features (theming, UI widgets, etc., etc.) would be a much bigger task. It's not necessary for your stated goal, it's more something you might consider for the sake of improving the robustness of your code by leveraging the quality of Drupal's APIs.

Comment: That sounds doable then, also drupal theming sounds good :)

Comment: Drupal's access system sounds good because we are getting data anyway from prestashop and bbulletin, also some custom data served like API access to two services. The main goal to achieve with this drupal is to get SEO and secure cms for frontend and perhaps some more security to that visitor backend. Like us having access to drupal's administration, we can do it trought module and just use building administration, can we ?

Comment: I'm not really clear what specifically you're asking. Basically you can build anything you like in a Drupal custom module. You could build a spaceship control system! What being in a Drupal module gives you is a) integration (to the extent that you want) of your module with your Drupal site and its admin backend (including additional functionality from 3rd party contrib modules), and b) use of Drupal's APIs which contain robust ways of achieving many common web programming needs.

Comment: I suspect the main question you need to consider is how radically you want to rearchitect your existing custom code in a fully Drupalized way, how you might have done it originally if you were using Drupal from the beginning. For example, you can do an enormous amount from the UI with Drupal modules like Feeds and Rules, to the extent that if you're clever you may not even need custom code.

Comment: Please accept my answer if you're happy with it; if you want wore help, I suggest starting new and much more specific question

Comment: Yes, thank you for your answer(s), I really would love to make it with drupal, I have had good experience with drupal but I'm not so experienced with modules and/or customizing drupal for needs, tho I have set forum/blog for tests also know how to edit templates etc but making larger project like this, not sure If drupal has too deep learning curve and it kills this project. Hopefully not